# django flatpages works with DEBUG=True, doesn't work with DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, django-flatpages

I can see that django looks for `500.html` when `DEBUG` is `False`.  What could be the problem?

Comment: If you have DEBUG=False, you don't see the stacktrace in the browser, but you can configure django to sent you a stacktrace in an email. Without it, you just don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Please search yourself. The django documentation is very good. One drawback: it is huge. But I am sure you will find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debug is set to False django renders the 500.html template instead of the debug stack-trace thing.

It might be that on a http 404 (not found) exception it tries to render the 404.html template and if it's not found than tries with the 500.html (internal error).

It is not a problem in itself but just a configuration.